# go bin - just 3 files

Tags: go, go-toolchain

I installed Go 1.6.2 on Windows but in my `bin` directory I now have only 3 files:

```
 go.exe
 godoc.exe
 gofmt.exe
```

I wonder if that's normal or my installation didn't go quite well.

Answer (score 3):

That's normal. If you're looking for all the other executables (like linker, compiler etc.), check the:

```
%GOROOT%/pkg/tool/windows_amd64
```

(or similar) folders. These are not placed in the `bin` folder because you don't need to call these (they are called by the `go.exe` tool). `bin` contains only the tools you interact with, and is recommended to add `%GOROOT%/bin` to your `PATH`.

For example in my `pkg/tool/windows_amd64` folder I have the following additional binaries:

```
addr2line.exe
api.exe
asm.exe
compile.exe
cover.exe
dist.exe
doc.exe
fix.exe
link.exe
nm.exe
objdump.exe
pack.exe
pprof.exe
tour.exe
trace.exe
vet.exe
yacc.exe
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. I was just worried that my installation did not go through quite fine.